# Lower type level values to term level in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-level-computation

For example in the following code can I fill the hole to always compute the `Nat` value corresponding to the type level `n` parameter?

```hs
 {-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, ExplicitForAll #-}
data Nat
  = Zero
  | Succ Nat

lower :: forall (n :: Nat) . Nat
lower = _

test0 = lower @Zero == Zero
test1 = lower @(Succ Zero) == Succ Zero
```

I tried using a type class:

```hs
class Lower (n :: Nat) where
  lower :: Nat

instance Lower Zero where
  lower = Zero

instance Lower n => Lower (Succ n) where
  lower = Succ (lower @n)
```

But then every time I want to use `lower` I need to explicitly require `Lower n`:

```hs
lower' :: forall (n :: Nat) . Lower n => Nat
lower' = lower @n
```

Comment: Types are erased (type parameters and type arguments don't exist at runtime). If you don't take some extra data in addition to the type, *of course* you can't get a runtime value. IMO this is a good thing, because you can choose for a type to *not* have a runtime impact if you want.

Comment: Maybe in the future we will get a variant of quantification that is not erased at runtime, e.g. `pi (n::Nat) . ...` vs `forall (n::Nat) . ...`, enabling "true" dependent types. Currently you instead need some typeclass constraint to make `n` available at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

As noted in the comments, in Haskell, type parameters are erased at runtime.  What this actually *means* is that the runtime behavior of a function depends only on the arguments supplied for its term-level parameters, never (directly) on the arguments supplied for its type-level parameters.

Put more directly, a function is a function of its term-level parameters only, and so the value of a function application is determined by the value of the term-level arguments, irrespective of the type-level arguments.  If we call the same function twice with the same term-level arguments but different type-level arguments, the two application will produce the same term-level result.

In practice, this is usually a distinction without a difference.  The function:

```
id :: forall a. a -> a
id x = x
```

has runtime behavior that depends only on its term-level parameter `x`.  If I call `id True` multiple times, it always produces the result `True`, irrespective of the type-level argument `a`.  BUT, obviously, if the term-level argument is `True`, then the type-level argument is necessarily `Bool`, so the question of whether `id True` would produce the same result with different type-level arguments for parameter `a` is moot.

But for your example, the question is not moot.  Your function:

```
lower :: (forall n :: Nat). Nat
```

must produce a value that depends only on its term-level parameters (of which there are none), and never on its type-level parameter `n`.  Multiple calls of `lower` with different type-level arguments will still have the same (nullary) term-level arguments, and so the call `lower` must always produce the same term-level result.  It is therefore impossible for `lower` to produce `Zero` for some type-level argument and `Succ Zero` for some other type-level argument.

A constraint is a "magical" term-level parameter.  Specifically, your `Lower n` constraint is syntactic sugar for a newtype parameter:

```
newtype CLower n = CLower { lower :: Nat }
```

that exhibits a "coherence" property such that for each possible value for the type-level parameter `n`, there is only one valid term-level value of type `CLower n`, and Haskell will automatically supply this (only possible) term-level value wherever it is needed.

So your type-class version of `lower'` is roughly equivalent to:

```
lower' :: (forall n :: Nat). CLower n -> Nat
lower' (CLower x) = x
```

with the appropriate `CLower n` argument automatically supplied where needed.

This provides a means for the type-level parameter to come pretty close to directly determining runtime behavior.  In this situation, it's still the case that `lower'` can only depend on its term-level parameter `CLower x`, but now this term-level parameter has a type (and so a value) that depends on the type-level parameter `n`.  If you call `lower'` with two different type-level arguments, Haskell automatically supplies two different term-level arguments, and the result of these two `lower'` calls can and will return two different term-level values.

If you want to avoid a constraint and still get two different results for two different type-level arguments, you must introduce *some other* term-level parameter on which `lower` can depend.  Trivially, you could write something like:

```
lower :: forall (n :: Nat). Int -> Nat
```

Now, `lower` has a term-level parameter (an integer), so it can produce different results for different term-level arguments:

```
lower 0 = Zero
lower m = Succ (lower (m-1))
```

This is not a very smart approach, of course, because the term-level parameter `m :: Int` is completely unrelated to the type-level `n :: Nat` parameter.  If you want your term-level parameter to somehow relate to the type-level parameter `n`, it must have a type that depends on `n`, like so:

```
lower :: forall (n :: Nat). Something n -> Nat
```

and you'll need to make `Something` into a GADT like:

```
data Something n where
    SZero :: Something Zero
    SSucc :: Something n -> Something (Succ n)
```

so you can write a body for `lower` that acts on different term-level arguments that in turn have been determined by the type-level argument:

```
lower :: forall (n :: Nat). Something n -> Nat
lower (SZero) = Zero
lower (SSucc n) = Succ (lower n)
```

This isn't very ergonomic for your use case because when it comes time to actually invoke `lower` with a particular type-level argument, you need to supply the matching term-level argument explicitly:

```
lower @Zero SZero
```

or, since Haskell can infer the type-level argument automatically, just:

```
lower SZero
```

and then you have to ask yourself why not just use the term-level `Zero` directly, if you still need to pass a term-level `SZero` around to call `lower`.

Still, term-level parameters that take the form of either constraints or GADTs are really the only mechanism to have a type-level parameter affect the runtime behavior of a function in the way you want.